# Generate text file (readable) file of specific size based on dictionary

Tags: python, bash, random, text

Is there a bash command (or alternative a python module) for generating a large file of specific size (e.g., 1GB) from random words contained on another file (e.g., the English dictionary or the Bible).

Example Input

```
Hello world.
How are you?
I am doing fine.
```

The output file should typically be larger than the "dictionary" input file.

Ideally, I would like the lines not to repeat.

Example Output:

```
Hello fine. world.
How you?
I doing am are fine.
world.
How Hello you?
are doing I am fine.
```

The above output is double the size of the original file (sorry if I skipped a word or punctuation symbol I did it by hand), but it has only contained in the file in random order.

I have experimented with shuf and truncate commands as other suggested as solutions to similar tasks but I am not sure they have all the properties for dealing with this problem.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: and post the dictionary structure/fragment

Comment: so it should be rather sentences than single words

Comment: Is that really what the input file looks like? Why not use a standard dictionary file, with one word per line, and no repeats? Also, what should the length of the output lines be? Is punctuation significant?

Comment: I don't have a restriction. Assuming I have a large book like the bible I would like to shuffle its contents and create something similar (I do not care if the sentences formed randomly make sense) but be of a specific user defined size typically, multiple times that of the original. My goal is to use the newly created files as dataset for benchmarking algorithms.

Comment: Does it have to be precisely 1 GB or can it be approximately that size?

Comment: @dr.doom. A dictionary file contains all the words found in any book. All you need to do is decide on a minimum and maximum length for each line, and then take an appropriate random sample from the dictionary. Keep a set of these random lines, checking that each line is not already in the set before adding it. For each added line, count the number of bytes it contains, and add it to a running total. When you reach the required number of bytes, stop, and write all the lines to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Here there is a concept of what you want. It will create the file you need, never repeating a line twice in a row. The only thing is that this wont be exactly 1GB. It will have a few bytes above that.

```
#!/bin/bash

touch some_output.txt

stream_of_words=$(cat words.txt | tr '\n' '|' | sed 's/|$//g')
qty_of_words=$( echo "$stream_of_words" | awk -F'|' '{ print NF }' )
last_number_used=1
random_number=1
limit_in_bytes=1073741824
size_of_file=$( wc -c some_output.txt | awk '{print $1}' )

echo "qty_of_words : $qty_of_words "
echo "size_of_file : $size_of_file"

while [[ $size_of_file -lt $limit_in_bytes ]]
do

    while [[ $random_number == $last_number_used ]]
    do
        random_number=$( awk -v qty="$qty_of_words" 'BEGIN { srand(); random_number=( int( rand() * 10000000 ) % qty ) + 1; print random_number }' )
    done

    last_number_used=$random_number
    random_word=$( awk -v arr="$stream_of_words" -v rnd="$random_number" 'BEGIN { srand(); arr_length=split(arr,list,"|"); print list[rnd] }' )
    echo "$random_word" 
    echo "$random_word" >> some_output.txt

    size_of_file=$( wc -c some_output.txt | awk '{print $1}' )

    sleep 1
done
```

This is the output I used, but you can change it for phrases in case you need :

```
$ cat words.txt
Banana
Apple
Peach
Watermelon
Onion
Potato
Orange
```

Regards!